# ASP.NET mvc pass parameter to form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

1) How to pass `id` in `AddBookInCategory` form in `@Html.EditorFor(model=>model.CategoryID)`.

2) And second how after adding new item in  `public ActionResult AddBookInCategory(Books book)` return to category with `id` it must be something like `return RedirectToAction("ShowBooksFromCategory", 1);` but it does not work.

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Home/
    TEntities TE = new TEntities();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult ShowCategories()
    {
        return View(TE.Category.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult ShowBooksFromCategory(int id)
    {
        return View(TE.Books.Where(key => key.CategoryID == id).ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult AddBookInCategory(int id)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddBookInCategory(Books book)
    {
        TE.Books.Add(book);
        TE.SaveChanges();
        return View();
        //return RedirectToAction("ShowBooksFromCategory", 1);
    }
}
```

AddBookInCategory.cshtml:

```
@model TestDataBase.Models.Books
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddBookInCategory";
}

<h2>AddBookInCategory</h2>

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>Book Name:</p>
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.BookName)
    <p>Category:</p>
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.CategoryID)
    <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("ShowCategories", "ShowCategories")
```

ShowBooksFromCategory.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestDataBase.Models.Books>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowBooksFromCategory";
}

<h2>ShowBooksFromCategory</h2>
<table>
    @foreach(var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @item.BookName
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

@Html.ActionLink("Add item", "AddBookInCategory", new {id=Model.Select(key=>key.CategoryID).FirstOrDefault() })
```

ShowCategories.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestDataBase.Models.Category>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowCategories";
}

<h2>ShowCategories</h2>

<table>
@foreach(var item in Model )
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @item.CategoryName
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("ShowBooksFromCategory", "ShowBooksFromCategory", new { id=item.CategoryID})
        </td>
    </tr>    
}
</table>
```

Models:

```
public partial class Books
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string BookName { get; set; }
    public int BookID { get; set; }
}
public partial class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer and then edited it. Check to see if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @A191919 To redirect with an int you can do the following (this is exactly the same thing you did within your actionlink to get the first form..)

```
return RedirectToAction("ShowBooksFromCategory",  new { id = book.CategoryID  });
```

To get the ID into your form you could use ViewBag.

```
    public ActionResult AddBookInCategory(int id)
    {
        ViewBag.id = id;
        return View();
    }
```

The use the viewbag value to fill in your form input.